# Multivariate Lagrange inversion

Tags: series-expansion

I know that the function `InverseSeries` ([Reference here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries.html)) provides an
interface for the Lagrange inversion formula.

However I can't find anything
on the multivariate inversion (i.e. for solving a system of series, for instance as explained [here](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~bacher/lagrange.pdf)). Is there
an implementation of this ? Or a way of doing so ?